# Conditional Tags for Custom Post Types

Tags: php, html, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I've just started using a custom post type for my site, and on some pages within this custom post type, for example:

/custom/post-one
/custom/post-three

I want to show some different content in the header. This is easy to do for pages like:

```
if (is_page(array('page-here','page-here','page-here','page-here'))) {
include(TEMPLATEPATH.'/header-red.php');
} 
elseif (is_page(array('page-here','page-here','page-here','page-here'))) {
include(TEMPLATEPATH.'/header-blue.php');
}
elseif (is_page(array('page-here'))) {
include(TEMPLATEPATH.'/header-green.php');
}  
else {
get_header();
}
```

How would I go about converting the above script I use for normal pages, to work on my custom post type pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now achieved this by using the Post ID as below:

```
if ( get_the_ID() == 4915 ) {
include(TEMPLATEPATH.'/header-red.php');
} 
elseif ( get_the_ID() == 7564 ) {
include(TEMPLATEPATH.'/header-blue.php');
}
elseif ( get_the_ID() == 71564 ) {
include(TEMPLATEPATH.'/header-green.php');
}  
else {
get_header();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this type of code into headr.php

```
if(is_singular( 'postType' )){
    //code which you want to render for this perticular post type   
}else{

    //your defalult code
}
```

In this code **postType** is your post type name.

Comment: Thanks, so instead of postType I would put what? The post title or the slug?

Comment: you need to put post type name by which you have registered your post type.

Comment: The thing is i want to target a single post within the custom post type, not all posts within the post type - does that make sense?